# Returning data from XML data in a column in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlxml

Trying to extract data from a column in a SQL Server table. The column however is not of type `XML` but the data is in XML format (see below). I can extract the data I need via the `CAST` function, but looking to see if there's a more efficient query to do so.

The data below exists in the `details` column of table `FoodTable`. I would like to query the table to get a list of all 'prod' (i.e. apple, blueberry, cherry) from `<FoodCity>`. The data is much larger in reality so would like help with more efficient query if possible.

I have the following:

```
SELECT
    CAST(details AS xml).value('(//GROCER/prod[@key="apple"]/@key)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS 'apple',
    CAST(details AS xml).value('(//GROCER/prod[@key="blueberry"]/@key)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS 'blueberry',
    CAST(details AS xml).value('(//GROCER/prod[@key="cherry"]/@key)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS 'cherry'
FROM 
    ABC.FoodTable
```

XML looks like this:

```
<GROCER>
    <FoodCity>
        <prod key = 'apple' value = '1.00'>
        <prod key = 'blueberry' value = '2.00'>
        <prod key = 'cherry' value = '5.00'>
    </FoodCity>
    <DiscountGrocer>
        <prod key = 'pear' value = '3.00'>
        <prod key = 'peach' value = '4.00'>
        <prod key = 'kiwi' value = '6.00'>
    </DiscountGrocer>
</GROCER>
```

Although my query above works, just looking to make it more efficient and simpler if possible.

### Output expected
| product   |

| apple     |
| blueberry |
| cherry    |

Thank you.

Comment: The presented XML is not well-formed. It doesn't have **key** attribute. Please fix it.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Thanks for the input. (1) table already exists with data and I'm only querying to verify various data exists. I didn't create or insert any data etc. unfortunately.  I think the sample data I posted is hopefully sufficient. There are other columns but irrelevant for query. (2) I would like to query the table, specifically the 'details' column of the table, for specific values and verify their existence. See example of my attempt to query 3 values.  (3), (4) will update post. Thank you for your answer. Having a look.

Comment: The sample query I posted would give me results I need but when querying say 20 items, the query grows much larger so wanted to just write something more efficient if possible.

Comment: MIchael, overall, we need ##1-4 to reproduce your environment and help you. It creates a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Michael, your query is very inefficient. Just take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting for your DDL and sample data population.
Here is a conceptual example.

It is using XQuery methods `.nodes()` and `.value()` to shred XML and convert it into a rectangular/relational format.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, details NVARCHAR(max));
INSERT INTO @tbl (details) VALUES
(N'<GROCER>
    <FoodCity>
        <prod key="apple" value="1.00"/>
        <prod key="blueberry" value="2.00"/>
        <prod key="cherry" value="5.00"/>
    </FoodCity>
    <DiscountGrocer>
        <prod key="pear" value="3.00"/>
        <prod key="peach" value="4.00"/>
        <prod key="kiwi" value="6.00"/>
    </DiscountGrocer>
</GROCER>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT id, CAST(details AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT c.value('@key', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS product
    , c.value('@value', 'DECIMAL(5,2)') AS price
FROM rs CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/GROCER/*/prod') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+-------+
|  product  | price |
+-----------+-------+
| apple     |  1.00 |
| blueberry |  2.00 |
| cherry    |  5.00 |
| pear      |  3.00 |
| peach     |  4.00 |
| kiwi      |  6.00 |
+-----------+-------+
```